# Can't get marker to display in nvd3 bullet chart when marker value is zero

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js, bulletedlist

I would like to display a marker on a bullet chart even when the number is zero; however, I can't find the area in either bullet.js or bulletChart.js where I can keep it from removing the marker. This is the example that I'm implementing in my project: http://nvd3.org/examples/bullet.html

The charts work otherwise, but I just can't get that to work.

Comment: Not sure if this would help at all, but I went to their live code part and specified this for the marker: `"markers": [0.5]`. It shows the marker pretty much at the zero point.

Comment: I'm using dynamic data, so I need it to return even when it's zero, plus I want it to return the correct number.

Answer (score 0):

Set it to the *text* "0", rather than the number.

Since you're using dynamic data, you'll need to do a special case check.